# New HTTP/1.1 php headers do not work?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I have been using a php script as IPN listener for years and it works fine.

A few days ago, Paypal set a message warning that October 7, 2013 code must be using HTTP/1.1. So I copied the sample code provided in lieu of my current headers :

-- new code---

```
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header="POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .="Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .="Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
```

-- Existing code ---

```
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Now the script no longer works. I get a 401 error :(

What's wrong ? I am growing extremely concerned, if new code does not work, that it will no work on time. Looked everywhere and could not find a definitive answer. I would like to get this working.

Help !

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close\r\n";

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Comment: Also remember that the responses are followed by `\r\n` from now on. Remove that with `$response = trim($response);` before you check whether the result is invalid/verified.